# Gmaps maps showing listings by Yellow pages

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created the map using Gmaps.js and passed the location and near by places to it but its showing listings by yellowpages.ca whenever I click a place following picture explains the problem. I am new in Google maps api.

[image]

```
var map;
var loc;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333,
        zoom:15,
      });

        GMaps.geocode({
          address: $('#address').val().trim(),
          callback: function(results, status){
            if(status=='OK'){
              var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                 lat=latlng.lat();
           lng=latlng.lng();         
    map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
              map.addMarker({
                lat: latlng.lat(),
                lng: latlng.lng(),
         icon:$('#mainPin').val().trim(),
              });

 loc=new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat(),latlng.lng());
}}});
});
function showplaces(place,urll){
map.removeMarkers();
GMaps.geocode({
          address: $('#address').val().trim(),
          callback: function(results, status){
            if(status=='OK'){
              var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
              map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
              map.addMarker({
                lat: latlng.lat(),
                lng: latlng.lng(),
        icon:$('#mainPin').val().trim(),
              });
      map.addLayer('places', {
          location : loc,
          radius : 500,
          types : [place],
          search: function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                map.addMarker({
                  lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
                  lng: place.geometry.location.lng(),
                  title : place.name,
                  icon:urll,

                });

              }
            } 
          }
        });  

      }
          }
        });

if(place=='shopping_mall')
   {
   GMaps.geocode({
          address: $('#address').val().trim(),
          callback: function(results, status){
            if(status=='OK'){
              var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
              map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
              map.addMarker({
                lat: latlng.lat(),
                lng: latlng.lng(),
        icon:$('#mainPin').val().trim(),
              });
      map.addLayer('places', {
          location : loc,
          radius : 500,
          types : ['shoe_store','store','department_store'],
          search: function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                map.addMarker({
                  lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
                  lng: place.geometry.location.lng(),
                  title : place.name,
                  icon:urll,

                });
              }
            } 
          }
        });  

      }
          }
        });



  }



 else if(place=='movie_theater')
   {
   GMaps.geocode({
          address: $('#address').val().trim(),
          callback: function(results, status){
            if(status=='OK'){
              var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
              map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
              map.addMarker({
                lat: latlng.lat(),
                lng: latlng.lng(),
        icon:$('#mainPin').val().trim(),
              });
      map.addLayer('places', {
          location :loc,
          radius : 500,
          types : ['movie_theater','zoo','stadium','night_club'],
          search: function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                map.addMarker({
                  lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
                  lng: place.geometry.location.lng(),
                  title : place.name,
                  icon:urll,

                });
              }
            } 
          }
        });  

      }
          }
        });

   }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see there are the attributions, it's required to show them.

Of course it's not required to show them multiple times.

The issue is(you may call it bug, I would call it a bad implementation ... heaven knows why so many people use these 3rd-party maps-libraries which  only introduce bugs instead of useful features).

The "bug": each time you call `map.addLayer('places')` a new instance of `google.maps.places.PlacesService` will be created. Each instance will print separate attributions.

Gmaps.js doesn't have options to:

- define where the attributions will be placed
- use a single instance of the `placesService`

My suggestion would be to give up this "library" .

When you  can't do without it check at the begin of `showplaces` if there is an object `map.singleLayers.places` . When it does it is the placesService-instance. Use this instance for a [`nearbySearch`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) instead of using `map.addLayer('places')` .

Comment: Thanks I am getting used to google maps api and its better than Gmap.js